# Replacing MacBook Pro Hard Drive?

Tags: macbook-pro

I need to replace the SSD on my MacBook Pro (13" Early 2015) but I can’t afford to get it done at the moment. I’ll need to try it myself. The model number for my MacBook Pro MF843LL/A and it says the drive is 512 GB flash_memory_solid_state. Can someone send me a link to the exact hard drive I need to get? I’ve never done this before and want to make sure I get the right one.

Comment: You need to open the case and check the exact drive - also make sure you have the serial number. I took a macbook pro 15" in and what was listed was **not** what was fitted...

Comment: Are you replacing because it's broken, or because you want  larger storage? Is 512 Gb the drive you have, or the drive you want?

Comment: It’s broken. 512 is the one I have.

Answer (score 1):

See https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-13-how-to-upgrade-ssd-storage.html for a lot of  details about how to upgrade the internal disk of a MacBook Pro, including information about compatible drive models and instruction on how to actually replace the drive.

It probably goes without saying, but **make sure you have a good backup before you start**.